# Keyboard and trackpad clicks doesn't work while installing or trying Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, 18.04, laptop, hp

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my fresh new HP Pavilion but my keyboard and trackpad clicks doesn't work anymore. So I'm unable to install or try Ubuntu on this laptop (dualboot from an USB key). The pre-installed Windows does work well with keyboard and trackpad.

Is this an Ubuntu issue, an HP issue or a combination of both and how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you able to open settings when you are using Ubuntu in Live mode?

Comment: That is not possible. I tried while booting the shift key to open the GRUB menu but the menu did not open. But even it was open, I can't save any modifications because I'm in 'try' mode.